# How can I display popup when graphic object is added in map using Arcgis Javascript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

We have to display callout popup for each graphic object that are available on map. i.e if point is created on map, it should be associated with callout popup which will display information about that point graphic. No need to create on point to show popup. So if 5 point object are on Map, callout for all 5 point should be displayed at once when these are created.

My question is how can I display such popup always for all points that are created on map?

Comment: As it stands this is not a real question, please state the question clearly. http://gis.stackexchange.com/helpcenter

Comment: This is definitely possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I know how to add popup when user click on any graphic point but our requirement is to show popup when graphic point is created. No need to click on that point to display popup. It should always be there.

Comment: You could add the popup on the onAdd event of the graphics layer. Have you tried that?